# CSVImporter starts importing after viewdidload [Swift]

Tags: swift, csv, csv-import

I want to import data from a .csv file, so I have used the CSVImporter https://github.com/Flinesoft/CSVImporter. It works well, but it starts the importing before the other part of the function viewDidLoad is executed.

The following code is only a test but I need either a solution that ensures that the CSVImporter completes importing before the other viewDidLoad code executes or a function which starts automatically after viewDidLoad.

Here is my code:

```
var Vokabeln: [[String]]?


var i = 0


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let path = "/Users/---CENSORED---/Documents/TestLöschen/TestLöschen/Vokabeln.csv"
    let importer = CSVImporter<[String]>(path: path, delimiter: ";")
    importer.startImportingRecords { $0 }.onFinish { importedRecords in
        for record in importedRecords {
            self.Vokabeln?[self.i][0] = record[0]
            self.Vokabeln?[self.i][1] = record[1]
            self.Vokabeln?[self.i][2] = record[2]
            print("Begin1")
            print(record[0])
            print(record[1])
            print(record[2])
            print("End1")
            self.i += 1
        }
    }

    print("Begin2")
    print(Vokabeln?[0][0])
    print(Vokabeln?[0][1])
    print(Vokabeln?[0][2])
    print(Vokabeln?[1][0])
    print(Vokabeln?[1][1])
    print(Vokabeln?[1][2])
    print("End2")
}
```

So first it prints "Begin2" and 6 times prints nil. Then, when the function viewDidLoad is finished, it prints "Begin1", then the correct variables and "End1"

Can anybody help me?
Thanks.

Comment: "CSVImporter works asynchronously by default and therefore doesn't block the main thread." Read the documentation about your lib. Don't block the main thread. Call the rest of your method on the `onFinish{}` closure. Or read the part `Import Synchronously`

Comment: @Larme I have made it Synchronously, but he prints nil nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

`startImportingRecords` works asynchronously, just put the code to print the `Vokabeln` in the completion handler after the repeat loop.

First of all you need to initialize the array otherwise nothing will be appended. And do not declare the array as optional and variable names are supposed to start with a lowercase letter.

```
var vokabeln = [[String]]()
```

In case to update the UI wrap the code in a dispatch block for example

```
importer.startImportingRecords { $0 }.onFinish { importedRecords in
    for record in importedRecords {
        self.vokabeln[self.i][0] = record[0]
        self.vokabeln[self.i][1] = record[1]
        self.vokabeln[self.i][2] = record[2]
        print("Begin1")
        print(record[0])
        print(record[1])
        print(record[2])
        print("End1")
        self.i += 1
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        print("Begin2")
        print(self.vokabeln[0][0])
        print(self.vokabeln[0][1])
        print(self.vokabeln[0][2])
        print(self.vokabeln[1][0])
        print(self.vokabeln[1][1])
        print(self.vokabeln[1][2])
        print("End2")
   }
}
```

But there is still another issue. If you declare the array as `[[String]]` both outer and inner arrays are empty and you cannot assign values with index subscripting. I recommend this syntax

```
for record in importedRecords {
    self.vokabeln.append(record) // this appends the whole record array
    print("Begin1")
    print(record)
    print("End1")
}
```

PS: Consider to use a more suitable text format like JSON or property list.

Comment: Because you are going to use it for concrete non-optional data. If no data could be received / converted the array is just empty. This is easier to use than optional bindings and you can omit all question marks. An optional should not be used as an alibi for *I-don't-care*.

Comment: and what is a dispatch block? The code with printing was only an example. The real code is way bigger.

Comment: It's the recommended way to execute the code within the braces on the main thread for example to update the user interface. You don't need it if no UI is involved or no other environment requires the main thread.

Comment: and when I try to intialise the variable without a queation mark, it gives the error "class viewcontroller has no intialisers"

Comment: This is impossible if you are using exactly the line in my answer (no colon `:` )

Comment: and when I make it in a dispatch queue like u said, it doesn't change anything... six times nil

Comment: when i make it one to one as you have said I get the error EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION on line 3

Comment: I updated the answer. Basically don't hard-code indexes without checking that the index is in the range.

Comment: I have found an other error. When I want to print vokabeln in for record, then it gets an error. I have testet other things and I have noticed that I can't declarate multiple arrays when they are optionals. 
`var Test: [[String]]?
Test![0][0] = "Hi"
        print(Test)`
There is an error in line 2

Comment: Once again, `[[String]]` – regardless of being optional or non-optional – is empty. **There is no index 0**, neither in the inner nor in the outer array. You need to **insert** or **append** objects to be able to use index subscripting. And also once again `var Test: [[String]]` does **not** *initialize* the array, you are only *declaring* it, the array is `nil`. Another argument not to use optionals.