# How to use synchronous import with custom mapping using CSVImporter

Tags: ios, swift, csv

I'm using CSVImporter to read data from a .csv table to fill an array which I use to populate a TableView. Now it seems that the array is correctly filled by CSVImporter, but the TableView is empty. Judging from this [previous question on SE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42860908/csvimporter-starts-importing-after-viewdidload-swift) I should rather use the synchronous import of CSVImporter. However, I couldn't figure out how to do this with a custom mapping.

The code I'm currently running is:

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "mydb", ofType: "csv")
let dataImporter = CSVImporter<DataClass>(path: path!)
dataImporter.startImportingRecords { recordValues -> DataClass in

    return DataClass(region: recordValues[0], id: Int(recordValues[1])!, name: recordValues[2], type: recordValues[3], start: Int(recordValues[4])!,  ... and so on)

        }.onFinish { importedData in

            for entry in importedData {
                self.mydata.append(entry)
            }

}
```

I know I can use something like

```
let mydata = dataImporter.importRecords { ... }
```

But since I need to map the data to DataClass as it is not just strings, I'm not sure how to do it - thanks for any help!

Comment: Try to understand how asynchronous data processing works. The imported data is returned – later – in the closure. Don't return anything, move the entire code which is supposed to run after *returning* **in** the completion closure.